Ошибка `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404` при загрузке HTML-таблицы с finance.yahoo.com
Помогите разобраться, почему следующий код выполняется с ошибкой urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found:
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GC%3DF/history/'
result = pd.read_html(url)
df = result[1]
print(df)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Там теперь нужно куки собирать и прочая лабуда. Вот тут в ответах есть рабочие примеры кода: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065035/yahoo-finance-v7-api-now-requiring-cookies-python  Как получите страницу - тогда уже можно будет её в пандас скормить. По-простому уже нельзя как раньше.
